# Linear regression print predicted value

Tags: python, linear-regression, valueerror

I have a mall dataset and i ran k-means with k = 5. Now after i ran linear regression i wanted to print my predicted value Y to compare with the actual value of Y. Printing the actual value was very easy but i keep getting an error when i try to print the predicted Y. To print the predicted value i used `df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})`. But i get an error `ValueError: array length 35 does not match index length 18`.

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\Mall_Customers.csv', usecols = ['Spending Score (1-100)', 'Annual Income (k$)'])


x = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)


kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=100, random_state=0)
y_kmeans= kmeans.fit_predict(x)

df0 = df[df.index.isin(mydict[0].tolist())]
Y = df0['Spending Score (1-100)']
X = df0[[ 'Annual Income (k$)','Age']]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

r_sq = regressor.score(X, Y)
print('coefficient of determination:', r_sq)


print('intercept:', regressor.intercept_)
print('slope:', regressor.coef_)


y_pred = regressor.predict(X)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})
print(df)
```

Comment: It should be ```y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)```, so that you can check it against y_test which is the same length

Comment: Thank you it worked! If you want post it as an answer to upvote and vote as a correct answer